# How can I solve this build error in android?

Tags: android, compiler-errors

`One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.5.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'`

Answer (score 0):

[ss for clear solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Bng.png)
here as shown in image goto android->gradleScript->build.gradle(modulelevel)
and then in that change compilesdk to 32 or higher.